# How do I download an SVN repository?

Tags: svn

What is the command to download an entire Subversion repository, i.e. the repository itself? I know that it is not `svn checkout` because that only downloads the head revision. I am looking for something similar to `git clone` or `hg clone`.

Comment: AFAIK, that's not functionality available through the client interface.

Comment: Look at svnsync or svnrdump commands

Answer (score 6):

As @Chris has said, SVN is not a distributed version control system, so downloading the entire repository is something done relatively infrequently and is not necessary for a normal user. Typically a user will only need to perform an `svn checkout`.

But utilities are provided for this as part of, say, a backup regime.

Historically the `svnadmin dump` command would be used. This assumes that you have local file access to the respository itself (eg. not just svn+ssh:\\ or http:\\). This command will dump the details of every commit in the specified revision range (eg. -r1:HEAD) to stdout.
Such a file can then be used to populate another repository, using the `svnadmin load` command.
See the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate) for usage details.

In addition, in version 1.7 of subversion a dump utility was introduced that was network aware, called `svnrdump`. This creates the same dump format file as the `svnadmin dump` command described above.
Again, see the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnrdump.html) for details.

Comment: What can `svnrdump` do? Does it recreate an SVN repository without requiring administrative rights or local file access?

Comment: @Melab - ``svnrdump`` will just create a dump file. You can then use that dump file to populate an empty repository on your local filesystem, using ``svnadmin load``. You'll still need local file access to create the repository.

Comment: So how would I use it with an SVN repository hosted on Google Code? `svnrdump dump https://<projectname>.googlecode.com/svn/`? `svnrdump dump https://<projectname>.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`?

Answer (score 2):

In contrast to git or hg, SVN is not a distributed version control system. There is no way to download the repository itself.

If you did download it (via ftp, for example) there would be no way to merge changes with the original repo.

Comment: You are wrong about "There is no way to download the repository itself". `svnsync` and `svnrdump` allow to copy a remote repository.

Comment: Sure you can copy it (as I said in the second paragraph) but I would contend that this is not "similar to git clone of hg clone". It's more like a traditional backup with strictly limited usefulness.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to get it without installing i was able to do it by running 
wget. use the below command to download the svn repo

```
wget -m -np http://myproject.googlecode.com/svn/myproject/trunk/
```